# Dual Twitter feeds with jquery fadeIn and setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, setinterval

I am making a project that shows two opposite views in two divs side-by-side. I have everything set up so the Tweets show in their respective div, but I'd like to make them both fade in, one tweet at a time (both sides can fade in at once, I don't mind that).

My Tweets are coming from an array, and I'm currently using the following code to push updates to the div:

```
for(var i=0; i < tweets.length; i++)
            {
                $("#proTweetList").prepend("<li><img src='" + tweets[i].profile_image_url + "' />" +
                    tweets[i].text+"</li>");
            }
```

and

```
for(var i=0; i < tweets.length; i++)
            {
                $("#antiTweetList").prepend("<li><img src='" + tweets[i].profile_image_url + "' />" +
                    tweets[i].text+"</li>");
            }
```

I found a great example on Stackoverflow, which is as follows:

```
var x=0; // The corner counter

function fading() {
  $("#corner"+(++x)).fadeIn(2000); // Fade in the current corner

  if (x==4) { // Last image to be faded in?
    clearInterval(); // Stop interval
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval("fading()",1000); // Call function every second
});
```

but I am very new to JQuery and cannot figure out how to translate this code into getting LI items in TWO different divs to fade in.

-- Derek

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < tweets.length; i++)
{
    var $item = $("<li style='display:none;'><img src='" + tweets[i].profile_image_url + "' />" +
    tweets[i].text+"</li>");
    $("#proTweetList").prepend($item);
    $item.fadeIn(2000);
}
```

Didn't test that piece of code though, but I think it will work. This will create the list item within a jQuery object($item), that way you can use functions like fade on it directly.

Comment: Would this not fade all the LI items in at once? The for loop will run through very quickly, and all items will be fading in over 2 seconds at almost exactly the same time (only offset by the speed it takes the for loop to activate the next fadeIn), won't they?

Comment: Yes it would, sorry, thought the tweets variable would only contain the new tweets. You could of course do a check that doesn't do display:none and fadeIn for tweets that already have been displayed(just make an array with all the unique ids of the tweets for that)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple plugin. This way you can attach the behaviour to as many divs as you like. I've written a very simple one (untested sorry) that may help:

```
;(function ($) {

    $.fn.loadtweets = function (options) {

        var settings = $.extend(
            {
                fadeTime : 1000,
                delay: 2000,
                tweets : array()
            },
            options
        );
        return this.each(
            function() {

                var _this = $(this),
                    tweets = settings.tweets,
                    index = 0;
                var loadTweet = function() {
                    if (tweets.length > index) {
                        _this.prepend("<li><img src='" + tweets[index].profile_image_url + "' />" +
                            tweets[index].text+"</li>").fadeIn(settings.fadeTime);
                        index++;
                        setTimeout(loadTweet, settings.delay);
                    }
                }
                loadTweet();

            }
        );
    };

})(jQuery);
```

You would call this plugin by going (I assume you have an array of tweets for each div):

```
$('#proTweetList').loadtweets({'tweets': proTweetsArray});
$('#antiTweetList').loadtweets({'tweets': antiTweetsArray});
```